# launch vim from python script and end script

Tags: python, linux, vim

I'm a newbie in programming in general, and with python in particular ...

I'm trying to write a python script, launched from a Linux Terminal, with a 'latex' file as an argument :

```
my_script.py file.tex.
```

I wish then my_script.py to open the file.tex in vim (in the Terminal), run another compiling script and then close, leaving 'file.tex' opened in vim and the compiling script running in background.

So, I tried :

```
myfile = "file.tex"
subprocess.call("vim "+ myfile)
subprocess.call("Latex_compiling_commande "+myfile)
```

but my_script.py is still waiting for vim to close before continuing, which is exaclty what subprocess.call is supposed to do, as explained in the : [official python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.call#subprocess.call).

I tried :

```
subprocess.Popen(["vim", myfile])
```

I've got an 'input/ouput error'...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably just call vim non-interactively.  See example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18865698/429982)

Comment: Thanks for your comment; but I wish to use vim with all its special capabilities (latex-suite plugin, mappings, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
import os
os.system("command")
```

For subprocess see this [link](https://parezcoydigo.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/call-vim-from-inside-a-python-script/)

Comment: Thanks invictus for your answer. 'os.system("commad")' does the same : vim open 'file.tex'; I can edit the file, save it, do whatever I want; it's only after closing vim that my_script.py continues with the compiler command.

Comment: Thanks for the link as well; I have already checked it, but I think (as far as I understood) my question is a bit different : what 'file.tex' contains does not interact in any way with 'my_script.py'

Comment: What I really do not understand, is that : `os.system("Latex_compiling_command "+ myfile)` followed by `os.system("vim "+myfile)` works fine ... (my_script.py only ends when closing vim). Is there really any way to launch vim, then the Latex compiling command and then having my_script.py to close (leaving file.tex opened in vim in the Terminal) ?